# How to set caret position in contenteditable with childs nodes?

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, caret

I have this code (he is not correct, but this gives an idea) :

```
function setCaret(contentEditable, pos) {
    if (contentEditable.hasChildNodes()) {
        var
            nodes = contentEditable.childNodes,
            pos2 = 0,
            cpt = 0,
            nb = nodes.length,
            node;

        for (cpt; cpt < nb && pos2 < pos; cpt++) {
            node = nodes[cpt];
            if (node.nodeType === 3) {
                pos2 += node.length;
            } else {
                pos2 += node.textContent.length;
            }
        }

        var textNode; 
        if (pos2 <= pos) {
            textNode = contentEditable.childNodes[cpt];
            pos = pos - pos2;
        } else {
            textNode = contentEditable.childNodes[cpt-1];
        }

        var range = document.createRange();
        range.setStart(textNode, pos);
        range.setEnd(textNode, pos);
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    }
}
```

The idea is to find the position of the good node based on the given position.

Example (pipe is the caret):

> Some ******bold****** |text.

- set position = 14
- 5 nodes [#text, b, #text, b, #text]
- node with caret (index of nodes) = *4*
- start position for node 4 : 13
- 14 - 13 = *1*

**range.setStart(nodes[4], 1);**

How to work my code in all cases please (javascript only (without library), IE optional) ?
Perhaps a simpler solution exists ?

(JSFiddle test : https://jsfiddle.net/mg4mm528/)

Answer (score -1):

With the help of execCommand you can achieve your goal.

```
document.execCommand ('bold', false, null);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand

Comment: Can you explain me how to do with `execCommand` ? I don't see.

Comment: Try this example of execCommand https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla

Comment: I just move the caret to a given position. My contenteditable may contain other nodes as bold and text.

Comment: Can you paste your code on fiddle it would be easy to solve your problem.

Comment: Maybe this is help you, i was set caret only textNode(3) https://jsfiddle.net/mg4mm528/2/

Comment: It's not bad, but with pos = 9 for example, it's not ok.